# java game - slick scroller - player can't move

Tags: java, animation, lwjgl, slick2d, scroller

My scroller is working but I **can't move player**.

Player is centering to middle of window screen. And map is centering to player's position.

Window (program) size is 640 x 640 px

Map *map.tmx* is *orthogonal* (zelda/pokemon style game).

Using only UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT keys (no diagonal moves).

what I am calculating or doing bad ?

```
public class Play extends BasicGameState {

    Animation movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;
    Animation player;
    String playerName = "Test";
    boolean quit = false;
    int[] duration = {200, 200, 200};
    int playerX = 0;
    int playerY = 0;
    int cameraX;
    int cameraY;
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    private TiledMap map = null;
    private static final float SPEED = 0.1f;

    public Play(int state, float x, float y) {
        playerX = (int) x;
        playerY = (int) y;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

        map = new TiledMap("map/map.tmx");

        Image[] walkUp = {
            new Image("graphics/player/up0.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/up1.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/up2.png")
        };

        Image[] walkDown = {
            new Image("graphics/player/down0.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/down1.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/down2.png")
        };
        Image[] walkLeft = {
            new Image("graphics/player/left0.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/left1.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/left2.png")
        };
        Image[] walkRight = {
            new Image("graphics/player/right0.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/right1.png"),
            new Image("graphics/player/right2.png")
        };

        movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
        movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);
        movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);
        movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);

        player = movingDown;

    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

        screenWidth = gc.getWidth();
        screenHeight = gc.getHeight();

        cameraX = (screenWidth / 2) - (playerX / 2);
        cameraY = (screenHeight / 2) - (playerY / 2);

        map.render(playerX, playerY);

        player.draw(cameraX, cameraY);

        g.drawString("X: " + playerX + "\nY: " + playerY, 520, 20);
        g.resetTransform();

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
            player = movingUp;
            player.update(delta);
            playerY += delta * SPEED;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
            player = movingDown;
            player.update(delta);
            playerY -= delta * SPEED;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
            player = movingLeft;
            player.update(delta);
            playerX += delta * SPEED;
        } else if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
            player = movingRight;
            player.update(delta);
            playerX -= delta * SPEED;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you have not provided the `player.update()` function, but it looks like you are drawing the player at `shiftX` and `shiftY` which never change. does the player animation work?

Comment: I can change directions of player, but only up0,down0,left0,right0 of animation will show

Comment: There is player.update(delta); in update method

Comment: can you maybe post a screenshot and explain what your desired outcome is?

Comment: Your player will be always at center of window screen. When you move with player, it will be still in center, but map will be scrolling on screen.

Comment: your code looks fine then, except that your directions are reversed. the only explanation for your behavior is that delta is always zero. try removing it from the update code, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea:

```
screenWidth = gc.getWidth();
screenHeight = gc.getHeight();

cameraX = (screenWidth / 2) - (playerX / 2);
cameraY = (screenHeight / 2) - (playerY / 2);

map.render(playerX, playerY);
player.draw(cameraX, cameraY);
```

Working in my example